# Redireccionar a login, si no esta autenticado

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Tengo un formulario de autenticación de usuarios que si es exitoso, guarda en variables de sesión (\Session) el id del usuario y el id de la compañía, pero en ocasiones cuando el servidor me cierra la sesión por limite de tiempo, o cuando el usuario intente ingresar a una ruta directamente sin pasar por login, el sistema me genera un error por falta de estas 2 variables de sesión.

Como hago para que cualquier ruta del sistema que se intente ejecutar, primero verifique si esta autenticado?, es con los Middleware?, como se utilizan?

Comment: Podrías guardarlos en una cookie, o en un token... hay muchas posibilidades. Considera reformular tu pregunta para que trate de algo particular. Consulta el [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para más información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En efecto, esto lo realiza un middleware de ruta, el cual se va a ejecutar en cada una de las rutas que lo utilicen.

En el archivo **routes.php**:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    // Las rutas que incluyas aquí pasarán por el middleware 'auth'
    Route::get('editar-usuario', 'UserController@edit');

});
```

En el archivo **app/Http/Kernel.php** es donde se definen los grupos de middleware (distinto a los grupos de ruta) y los middleware:

```
<?php

namespace app\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    // ......

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth'          => Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        // otros middleware
    ];

    // ....
}
```

Por último, el archivo del Middleware, ubicado en **app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php**:

```
<?php

namespace app\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {

        // si la persona no inició sesión, entonces ....
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {

            if ($request->ajax()) {

                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);

            } else {

                // si la persona no inició sesión y no es una solicitud ajax
                // enviar al formulario de ingreso
                return redirect()->guest('entrar');

            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Toda la documentación de middlewares la encuentras acá: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#registering-middleware